# Where can I find open-source weather forecast software?

Tags: specific-reference, simulations, software, weather, meteorology

Are there any software packages/frameworks for running weather forecast numeric models on a single PC? I've found at least two instances, but I'm interested to know whether there are more and where I may find it.

My preference is for

1. open-source software (but other licensing schemes can be considered), to be used for personal use (i.e. not professional/enterprise use) and study;
2. synoptic weather forecast (assuming I would be providing the input weather data in some way, as well possibly other frontier-conditions such as orography, etc), but will also consider software more oriented for mesoscale, climatology, etc;
3. software that can run on single PCs, but I'd also like to know about software which runs on a multi-node networked environment (e.g. dedicated "farm").

If you'd also care to provide, I would also be interested to know about what input format is used for the setup, what numeric models it uses (hydrostatic, ...), and any other information you'd care to provide; or just point me to the page which describes that.  :-)

So far I've only found [MM5](http://www.mmm.ucar.edu/mm5/) (which the authors affirm to be of public domain) and [WRF](http://www.wrf-model.org/) as candidates, but I've neither tried downloading let alone setting it up to see how it works (in other words, I'm still just idly browsing, not actively persuing attempts to install, run, etc). So I'm asking if these are the only ones available more or less freely, or if there are others. Other software frameworks appear to be available under paid licenses (e.g. some things from the ECMWF) and I'm not too sure whether they source code is provided. So I'm basically asking to know what's out there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find something on this page, if not, on the site somewhere.
I have not checked it out tonight, but I am sure I have seen programs there, in the past.

http://www.realclimate.org/index.php/data-sources/

Clive Ballard

Comment: There is also a lot of good info on this site, with regards to weather and other properties of the planets, etc.  Example: Some good information with regard to Venus climate and the recent "Venus Express" mission, can be found at:

http://www.realclimate.org/index.php/archives/2008/03/venus-unveiled/

Some of the comments also contain good info, but there are,a lot of them. >200. If looking for more, or different info, Try a site search for Venus. Quite a lot there. From its Domain Name, this info, is probably, not what you would expect to find here. Clive Ballard